# Container Registry doesn't work with dockerized gitlab behind https

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a dockerized Gitlab and Gitlab-runner but the runner doen't seem to be able to contact the registry.

Here is the log of the job:

```
$ echo $CI_REGISTRY_USER
gitlab-ci-token
$ echo $CI_REGISTRY
EXAMPLE.COM:5050
$ echo $SERVER_IP
[MASKED]
$ echo $SERVER_USER
[MASKED]
$ echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
time="2023-11-19T23:28:49Z" level=info msg="Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint" error="Get \"https://EXAMPLE.COM:5050/v2/\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-19T23:28:49Z is after 2022-10-15T12:39:37Z"
Get "https://EXAMPLE.COM:5050/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-19T23:28:49Z is after 2022-10-15T12:39:37Z
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The thing is that my certificate is valid when I go to my Gitlab web instance on https://EXAMPLE.COM.

Here is how I launch my dockerized Gitlab + Gitlab-runner with docker compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    hostname: EXAMPLE.COM
    ports:
      - "4433:443"
      - "8080:80"
      - "2222:22"
      - "5005:5005"
    volumes:
      - /data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - /data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    restart: always
    networks:
      - gitlab
  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /data/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner
    networks:
      - gitlab

networks:
  gitlab:
    name: gitlab-network
```

And here is the NGINX config:

```
server {
  server_name EXAMPLE.COM;
  client_max_body_size 50m;
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = EXAMPLE.COM) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name EXAMPLE.COM;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
  listen 5050 ssl;
  server_name EXAMPLE.COM;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Everything seems fine. Here is my gitlab.rb file, as I suppose I have some lines to change:

```
external_url 'https://EXAMPLE.COM'




################################################################################
## gitlab.yml configuration
##! Docs: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/gitlab.yml.md
################################################################################
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'ssh.host_example.com'
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_user'] = ''
# gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'UTC'

### Rails asset / CDN host
###! Defines a url for a host/cdn to use for the Rails assets
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#set-a-content-delivery-network-url
# gitlab_rails['cdn_host'] = 'https://mycdnsubdomain.fictional-cdn.com'

### GitLab email server settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html
###! **Use smtp instead of sendmail/postfix.**

# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.server"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
# gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "smtp user"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "smtp password"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
# gitlab_rails['smtp_pool'] = false

###! **Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert'**
###! Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
# gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'

# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"

### Trusted proxies
###! Customize if you have GitLab behind a reverse proxy which is running on a
###! different machine.
###! **Add the IP address for your reverse proxy to the list, otherwise users
###!   will appear signed in from that address.**
# gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = []

### Content Security Policy
####! Customize if you want to enable the Content-Security-Policy header, which
####! can help thwart JavaScript cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.
####! See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP
# gitlab_rails['content_security_policy'] = {
#  'enabled' => false,
#  'report_only' => false,
#  # Each directive is a String (e.g. "'self'").
#  'directives' => {
#    'base_uri' => nil,
#    'child_src' => nil,
#    'connect_src' => nil,
#    'default_src' => nil,
#    'font_src' => nil,
#    'form_action' => nil,
#    'frame_ancestors' => nil,
#    'frame_src' => nil,
#    'img_src' => nil,
#    'manifest_src' => nil,
#    'media_src' => nil,
#    'object_src' => nil,
#    'script_src' => nil,
#    'style_src' => nil,
#    'worker_src' => nil,
#    'report_uri' => nil,
#  }
# }

### Allowed hosts
###! Customize the `host` headers that should be catered by the Rails
###! application. By default, everything is allowed.
# gitlab_rails['allowed_hosts'] = []



### Consolidated (simplified) object storage configuration
###! This uses a single credential for object storage with multiple buckets.
###! It also enables Workhorse to upload files directly with its own S3 client
###! instead of using pre-signed URLs.
###!
###! This configuration will only take effect if the object_store
###! sections are not defined within the types. For example, enabling
###! gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_enabled'] or
###! gitlab_rails['lfs_object_store_enabled'] will prevent the
###! consolidated settings from being used.
###!
###! Be sure to use different buckets for each type of object.
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['enabled'] = false
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = {}
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['storage_options'] = {}
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['proxy_download'] = false
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['artifacts']['bucket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['external_diffs']['bucket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['lfs']['bucket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['uploads']['bucket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['packages']['bucket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['dependency_proxy']['bucket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['terraform_state']['bucket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['ci_secure_files']['bucket'] = nil

### Job Artifacts
# gitlab_rails['artifacts_enabled'] = true
# gitlab_rails['artifacts_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts"
####! Job artifacts Object Store
####! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html#using-object-storage
# gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_enabled'] = false
# gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_proxy_download'] = false
# gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_remote_directory'] = "artifacts"
# gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_connection'] = {
#   'provider' => 'AWS',
#   'region' => 'eu-west-1',
#   'aws_access_key_id' => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
#   'aws_secret_access_key' => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
#   # # The below options configure an S3 compatible host instead of AWS
#   # 'aws_signature_version' => 4, # For creation of signed URLs. Set to 2 if provider does not support v4.
#   # 'endpoint' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com', # default: nil - Useful for S3 compliant services such as DigitalOcean Spaces
#   # 'host' => 's3.amazonaws.com',
#   # 'path_style' => false # Use 'host/bucket_name/object' instead of 'bucket_name.host/object'
# }

### Git LFS
# gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true
# gitlab_rails['lfs_storage_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/lfs-objects"
# gitlab_rails['lfs_object_store_enabled'] = false
# gitlab_rails['lfs_object_store_proxy_download'] = false
# gitlab_rails['lfs_object_store_remote_directory'] = "lfs-objects"
# gitlab_rails['lfs_object_store_connection'] = {
#   'provider' => 'AWS',
#   'region' => 'eu-west-1',
#   'aws_access_key_id' => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
#   'aws_secret_access_key' => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
#   # # The below options configure an S3 compatible host instead of AWS
#   # 'aws_signature_version' => 4, # For creation of signed URLs. Set to 2 if provider does not support v4.
#   # 'endpoint' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com', # default: nil - Useful for S3 compliant services such as DigitalOcean Spaces
#   # 'host' => 's3.amazonaws.com',
#   # 'path_style' => false # Use 'host/bucket_name/object' instead of 'bucket_name.host/object'
# }

### GitLab uploads
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/uploads.html
# gitlab_rails['uploads_directory'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads"
# gitlab_rails['uploads_storage_path'] = "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public"
# gitlab_rails['uploads_base_dir'] = "uploads/-/system"
# gitlab_rails['uploads_object_store_enabled'] = false
# gitlab_rails['uploads_object_store_proxy_download'] = false
# gitlab_rails['uploads_object_store_remote_directory'] = "uploads"
# gitlab_rails['uploads_object_store_connection'] = {
#   'provider' => 'AWS',
#   'region' => 'eu-west-1',
#   'aws_access_key_id' => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
#   'aws_secret_access_key' => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
#   # # The below options configure an S3 compatible host instead of AWS
#   # 'host' => 's3.amazonaws.com',
#   # 'aws_signature_version' => 4, # For creation of signed URLs. Set to 2 if provider does not support v4.
#   # 'endpoint' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com', # default: nil - Useful for S3 compliant services such as DigitalOcean Spaces
#   # 'path_style' => false # Use 'host/bucket_name/object' instead of 'bucket_name.host/object'
# }


### CI Secure Files
# gitlab_rails['ci_secure_files_enabled'] = false
# gitlab_rails['ci_secure_files_storage_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/ci_secure_files"
# gitlab_rails['ci_secure_files_object_store_enabled'] = false
# gitlab_rails['ci_secure_files_object_store_remote_directory'] = "ci-secure-files"
# gitlab_rails['ci_secure_files_object_store_connection'] = {
#   'provider' => 'AWS',
#   'region' => 'eu-west-1',
#   'aws_access_key_id' => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
#   'aws_secret_access_key' => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
#   # # The below options configure an S3 compatible host instead of AWS
#   # 'host' => 's3.amazonaws.com',
#   # 'aws_signature_version' => 4, # For creation of signed URLs. Set to 2 if provider does not support v4.
#   # 'endpoint' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com', # default: nil - Useful for S3 compliant services such as DigitalOcean Spaces
#   # 'path_style' => false # Use 'host/bucket_name/object' instead of 'bucket_name.host/object'
# }

################################################################################
## Container Registry settings
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html
################################################################################

# registry_external_url 'https://registry.example.com'
 registry_external_url 'https://EXAMPLE.COM:5050'

### Settings used by GitLab application
# gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
# gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "registry.gitlab.example.com"
# gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5005"
# gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry"

# Notification secret, it's used to authenticate notification requests to GitLab application
# You only need to change this when you use external Registry service, otherwise
# it will be taken directly from notification settings of your Registry
# gitlab_rails['registry_notification_secret'] = nil

###! **Do not change the following 3 settings unless you know what you are
###!   doing**
# gitlab_rails['registry_api_url'] = "http://localhost:5000"
# gitlab_rails['registry_key_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/certificate.key"
# gitlab_rails['registry_issuer'] = "omnibus-gitlab-issuer"

### Settings used by Registry application
 registry['enable'] = true
# registry['username'] = "registry"
# registry['group'] = "registry"
# registry['uid'] = nil
# registry['gid'] = nil
# registry['dir'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/registry"
# registry['registry_http_addr'] = "localhost:5000"
# registry['debug_addr'] = "localhost:5001"
# registry['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/registry"
# registry['env_directory'] = "/opt/gitlab/etc/registry/env"
# registry['env'] = {
#   'SSL_CERT_DIR' => "/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs/"
# }
# registry['log_level'] = "info"
# registry['log_formatter'] = "text"
# registry['rootcertbundle'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/registry/certificate.crt"
# registry['health_storagedriver_enabled'] = true
# registry['middleware'] = nil
# registry['storage_delete_enabled'] = true
# registry['validation_enabled'] = false
# registry['autoredirect'] = false
# registry['compatibility_schema1_enabled'] = false


### Registry backend storage
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#configure-storage-for-the-container-registry
# registry['storage'] = {
#   's3' => {
#     'accesskey' => 's3-access-key',
#     'secretkey' => 's3-secret-key-for-access-key',
#     'bucket' => 'your-s3-bucket',
#     'region' => 'your-s3-region',
#     'regionendpoint' => 'your-s3-regionendpoint'
#   },
#   'redirect' => {
#     'disable' => false
#   }
# }

### Registry notifications endpoints
# registry['notifications'] = [
#   {
#     'name' => 'test_endpoint',
#     'url' => 'https://gitlab.example.com/notify2',
#     'timeout' => '500ms',
#     'threshold' => 5,
#     'backoff' => '1s',
#     'headers' => {
#       "Authorization" => ["AUTHORIZATION_EXAMPLE_TOKEN"]
#     }
#   }
# ]
### Default registry notifications
# registry['default_notifications_timeout'] = "500ms"
# registry['default_notifications_threshold'] = 5
# registry['default_notifications_backoff'] = "1s"
# registry['default_notifications_headers'] = {}


################################################################################
## CI_JOB_JWT
################################################################################
##! RSA private key used to sign CI_JOB_JWT
# gitlab_rails['ci_jwt_signing_key'] = nil # Will be generated if not set.




################################################################################
## GitLab NGINX
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html
################################################################################

# nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '100m'
#nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
#nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
#nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80

##! Most root CA's are included by default
# nginx['ssl_client_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/ca.crt"

##! enable/disable 2-way SSL client authentication
# nginx['ssl_verify_client'] = "off"

##! if ssl_verify_client on, verification depth in the client certificates chain
# nginx['ssl_verify_depth'] = "1"

# nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/#{node['fqdn']}.crt"
# nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/#{node['fqdn']}.key"
# nginx['ssl_ciphers'] = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
# nginx['ssl_prefer_server_ciphers'] = "off"

##! **Recommended by: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html
##!                   https://cipherli.st/**
# nginx['ssl_protocols'] = "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"

##! **Recommended in: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html**
# nginx['ssl_session_cache'] = "shared:SSL:10m"

##! **Recommended in: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&version=1.17.7&config=intermediate&openssl=1.1.1d&ocsp=false&guideline=5.6**
# nginx['ssl_session_tickets'] = "off"

##! **Default according to https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html**
# nginx['ssl_session_timeout'] = "1d"

# nginx['ssl_dhparam'] = nil # Path to dhparams.pem, eg. /etc/gitlab/ssl/dhparams.pem
# nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['*', '[::]']

##! **Defaults to forcing web browsers to always communicate using only HTTPS**
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#setting-http-strict-transport-security
# nginx['hsts_max_age'] = 63072000
# nginx['hsts_include_subdomains'] = false

##! Defaults to stripping path information when making cross-origin requests
# nginx['referrer_policy'] = 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin'

##! **Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html**
# nginx['gzip_enabled'] = true

##! **Override only if you use a reverse proxy**
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#setting-the-nginx-listen-port
nginx['listen_port'] = 80

##! **Override only if your reverse proxy internally communicates over HTTP**
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#supporting-proxied-ssl
nginx['listen_https'] = false

##! **Override only if you use a reverse proxy with proxy protocol enabled**
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#configuring-proxy-protocol
# nginx['proxy_protocol'] = false

# nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location ^~ /foo-namespace/bar-project/raw/ {\n deny all;\n}\n"
# nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf;"
# nginx['proxy_read_timeout'] = 3600
# nginx['proxy_connect_timeout'] = 300
# nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
#  "Host" => "$http_host_with_default",
#  "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
#  "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
#  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
#  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on",
#  "Upgrade" => "$http_upgrade",
#  "Connection" => "$connection_upgrade"
# }
# nginx['proxy_cache_path'] = 'proxy_cache keys_zone=gitlab:10m max_size=1g levels=1:2'
# nginx['proxy_cache'] = 'gitlab'
# nginx['proxy_custom_buffer_size'] = '4k'
# nginx['http2_enabled'] = true
# nginx['real_ip_trusted_addresses'] = []
# nginx['real_ip_header'] = nil
# nginx['real_ip_recursive'] = nil
# nginx['custom_error_pages'] = {
#   '404' => {
#     'title' => 'Example title',
#     'header' => 'Example header',
#     'message' => 'Example message'
#   }
# }

### Advanced settings
# nginx['dir'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/nginx"
# nginx['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/nginx"
# nginx['error_log_level'] = "error"
# nginx['worker_processes'] = 4
# nginx['worker_connections'] = 10240
# nginx['log_format'] = '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request_method $filtered_request_uri $server_protocol" $status $body_bytes_sent "$filtered_http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $gzip_ratio'
# nginx['sendfile'] = 'on'
# nginx['tcp_nopush'] = 'on'
# nginx['tcp_nodelay'] = 'on'
# nginx['hide_server_tokens'] = 'off'
# nginx['gzip_http_version'] = "1.0"
# nginx['gzip_comp_level'] = "2"
# nginx['gzip_proxied'] = "any"
# nginx['gzip_types'] = [ "text/plain", "text/css", "application/x-javascript", "text/xml", "application/xml", "application/xml+rss", "text/javascript", "application/json" ]
# nginx['keepalive_timeout'] = 65
# nginx['keepalive_time'] = '1h'
# nginx['cache_max_size'] = '5000m'
# nginx['server_names_hash_bucket_size'] = 64
##! These paths have proxy_request_buffering disabled
# nginx['request_buffering_off_path_regex'] = "/api/v\\d/jobs/\\d+/artifacts$|/import/gitlab_project$|\\.git/git-receive-pack$|\\.git/gitlab-lfs/objects|\\.git/info/lfs/objects/batch$"

### Nginx status
# nginx['status'] = {
#  "enable" => true,
#  "listen_addresses" => ["127.0.0.1"],
#  "fqdn" => "dev.example.com",
#  "port" => 9999,
#  "vts_enable" => true,
#  "options" => {
#    "server_tokens" => "off", # Don't show the version of NGINX
#    "access_log" => "off", # Disable logs for stats
#    "allow" => "127.0.0.1", # Only allow access from localhost
#    "deny" => "all" # Deny access to anyone else
#  }
# }

##! Service name used to register Nginx as a Consul service
# nginx['consul_service_name'] = 'nginx'
##! Semantic metadata used when registering NGINX as a Consul service
# nginx['consul_service_meta'] = {}

################################################################################
## GitLab CI
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/README.html
################################################################################

# gitlab_ci['gitlab_ci_all_broken_builds'] = true
# gitlab_ci['gitlab_ci_add_pusher'] = true
# gitlab_ci['builds_directory'] = '/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/builds'



################################################################################
## Registry NGINX
################################################################################

# All the settings defined in the "GitLab Nginx" section are also available in
# this "Registry NGINX" section, using the key `registry_nginx`.  However, those
# settings should be explicitly set. That is, settings given as
# `nginx['some_setting']` WILL NOT be automatically replicated as
# `registry_nginx['some_setting']` and should be set separately.

# Below you can find settings that are exclusive to "Registry NGINX"
# registry_nginx['enable'] = true

# registry_nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
#  "Host" => "$http_host",
#  "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
#  "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
#  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
#  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
# }

# When the registry is automatically enabled using the same domain as `external_url`,
# it listens on this port
#registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true;
#registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5050
#registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false

################################################################################
# Let's Encrypt integration
################################################################################
# letsencrypt['enable'] = nil
# letsencrypt['contact_emails'] = [] # This should be an array of email addresses to add as contacts
# letsencrypt['group'] = 'root'
# letsencrypt['key_size'] = 2048
# letsencrypt['owner'] = 'root'
# letsencrypt['wwwroot'] = '/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/www'
# See http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html#automatic-renewal for more on these sesttings
# letsencrypt['auto_renew'] = true
# letsencrypt['auto_renew_hour'] = 0
# letsencrypt['auto_renew_minute'] = nil # Should be a number or cron expression, if specified.
# letsencrypt['auto_renew_day_of_month'] = "*/4"
# letsencrypt['auto_renew_log_directory'] = '/var/log/gitlab/lets-encrypt'

##! Turn off automatic init system detection. To skip init detection in
##! non-docker containers. Recommended not to change.
# package['detect_init'] = true

##! Attempt to modify kernel paramaters. To skip this in containers where the
##! relevant file system is read-only, set the value to false.
# package['modify_kernel_parameters'] = true

##! Specify maximum number of tasks that can be created by the systemd unit
##! Will be populated as TasksMax value to the unit file if user is on a systemd
##! version that supports it (>= 227). Will be a no-op if user is not on systemd.
# package['systemd_tasks_max'] = 4915

##! Settings to configure order of GitLab's systemd unit.
##! Note: We do not recommend changing these values unless absolutely necessary
# package['systemd_after'] = 'multi-user.target'
# package['systemd_wanted_by'] = 'multi-user.target'
```

I tried to edit the config.rb inspired by this website: http://blog.programster.org/dockerized-gitlab-enable-container-registry

Up to no avail: the gitlab didn't work at all after the modifications.

Comment: It looks like you configured the regular gitlab nginx for use behind a reverse proxy with TLS termination, but you haven't done so for the container registry nginx. The NGINX `server` section describing the listener on port 5050 also doesn't have any proxy pass instructions, so it's not clear to me how that configuration is supposed to be expected to pass traffic to the gitlab container registry... the ultimate error appears to be a certificate issue though.  The message `current time 2023-11-19T23:28:49Z is after 2022-10-15T12:39:37Z` appears to indicate an expired certificate...